# SQL that group specific columns and do manipulation on each group

Tags: mysql

For example I have this data base,

```
-- playerName -- | -- level -- | -- score -- | -- timePlayed -- |

   momo          |     1       |      6      |       2345       |
   koko          |     1       |      7      |       4347       |
   roro          |     1       |      3      |       1234       |
   lolo          |     1       |      9      |       2345       |
   bobo          |     1       |      2      |       4347       |
   momo          |     2       |      1      |       6789       |
   koko          |     2       |      1      |       9999       |
   roro          |     2       |      4      |       1001       |
   lolo          |     2       |      7      |       3456       |
   bobo          |     2       |      3      |       8453       |
```

Let's say I have lots of levels and lots of players.
I want to group each level select the top 3 of each group ( only between some levels) and order them by some parameters.

I tried to write some code.

```
SELECT *
FROM Levels
WHERE level > 0 and level < 15 
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY score desc , timePlayed desc
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

I want the output to look like it:

```
-- playerName -- | -- level -- | -- score -- | -- timePlayed -- |

   lolo          |     1       |      9      |       2345       |
   koko          |     1       |      7      |       4347       |
   momo          |     1       |      6      |       2345       |
   lolo          |     2       |      7      |       3456       |
   roro          |     2       |      4      |       1001       |
   bobo          |     2       |      3      |       8453       |
```

And my output is not even close to the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the top three of each group is a pain in MySQL.  The easiest way may be to use variables:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             (@rn := if(@l = level, @rn + 1,
                        if(@l := level, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from levels l cross join
           (select @l := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by level, score desc, timeplayed desc
     ) l
where rn <= 3;
```

Comment: its working like a magic . can you please explain what did you do or  give me a link where i can read about it ?

Comment: @OriYampolsky . . . I'm not sure what you don't understand.  I suppose the place to start is by looking at the MySQL documentation on variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php. 
HAVING COUNT (*) <= 3 will do the trick.